# Iframe should automatically be full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user opens my website on a smartphone the iframe should auto full screen. I am facing this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: fullscreen error Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on **'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.**

When I run this code:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
     // which element will be fullscreen
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#container iframe');
    // Do fullscreen
    if (iframe.requestFullscreen) {
      iframe.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (iframe.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      iframe.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (iframe.msRequestFullscreen) {
      iframe.msRequestFullscreen();
    }   
        
    }
});
```

Comment: What is unclear about that error? You can't work around not having a user interaction to set fullscreen or it would be heavily abused